# $\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{a^3+b+c+d} \leq \frac {a+b+c+d}{4}$ for $a, b, c, d>0$ which satisfies $abcd=1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{1}{a^3+b+c+d} \leq \dfrac {a+b+c+d}{4}$ for $a, b, c, d>0$ which satisfies $abcd=1$.

I first lessened the range.
$$
\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {1} {a^3+b+c+d} \leq \sqrt[4]{abcd} = 1.
$$

Also, I thought about this one:
\begin{align}
&a^3+b+c+d \geq 4 \ \sqrt[4]{a^3bcd} = 4\sqrt{a}. \\
&\Rightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {1} {4\sqrt{a}} \leq \dfrac {1} {4} \sum_{cyc} a.
\end{align}
p.s. For the last one, it doesn't satisfy Muirhead's inequality conditions.

Comment: A quartic root is better typeset as `\sqrt[4]{...}`

Comment: 1) You strengthened the condition quite significantly. While the inequality is still true, it could take a lot more work. 2) Your second approach isn't true. EG as $ a\rightarrow 0 $, because the AM-GM "over accounted for $a$". 3) Hint: $( a^3 +b+c+d)(1/a + b+c+d) \geq ??$